# Doctrine2 / MySQL - Create an auto increment field on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, multiple-columns, auto-increment

I wanted to know if it is possible to have an auto increment field based on multiple columns ?

Here is my problem : 
I have a table which stores CARTS in LINES. I have a unique id for each carts but I also want to generate a unique id for each line. So I can have a unique CART ID inside a line.

Actually, I want to exactly do the same as in this example from the MySQL doc :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

The id increments within the grp column.

I'm a bit lost with primary key / index and I don't know if I have to use these in order to generate my ids.

I tried to add this to my symfony entity, but it didn't generate a new column with the id I want.

```
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="line_idx", columns={"line_id"})})
```

Comment: No idea about your PHP frameworks but MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT is just a table-wide counter. If you want your DB to take care of your lines you'll have to write some kind of stored routine.

Comment: Alright, thanks ! I can do it "by hand" with PHP but I hoped either Doctrine2 or MySQL could handle it for me. I'm sure I can do some tricky things with this ` PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)`, but I don't know how to use it through doctrine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I managed to do what I want, I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it but here is how I did:

I added my cart_id field :

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cart_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
*/
private $cart_id;
```

Then, I added a unique contraint, just to be sure everything is unique :

```
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="cart_idx", columns={"line_id", "cart_id"})})
```

Then, I made a repository function to get the last cart_id for a given line  (there is a ManyToOne relation between my cart and my line:

```
<?php

namespace CM\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * CartRepository
 */
class CartRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getLastCartIdForLine($lineId) {
            return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->select('c.cart_id')
                        ->join('c.line','l')
                        ->andWhere('l.id = :lineId')
                        ->setParameter('lineId', $lineId)
                        ->orderBy('c.id', 'DESC')
                        ->setMaxResults(1)
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getSingleScalarResult();
    }       
}
```

And I finally do this :

```
$cart = new Cart;
$lastCartId = $em->getRepository('CMPlatformBundle:Cart')->getLastCartIdForLine($lineId);
$cart->setCartId($lastCartId+1);
$em->persist($cart);
```

It works, not sure if it was the best way to handle this. Let me know if you find something better.

Comment: Be careful, if there is no entry to retrieve, ->getSingleScalarResult() will raise an error, so you have to consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably what you're trying to do:

```php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Animal
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="animals")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Animal
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="grp", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $grp;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

Basically you flag both attributes `id` and `grp` with the `@Id` annotation so that both will be part of the primary key. Then you flag just the `id` with the `@GeneratedValue` annotation to make it auto increment.

Make sure you're using **MyISAM** though because it looks like this feature is not supported by **InnoDB**.

**Note:** The `@GeneratedValue` annotation must always be part of an attribute flag as `@Id` as explained in the [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#generatedvalue).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I didn't manage to make it work. I got this error : `[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity`.

I think I will do it by hand, it will be easier.